# Why C++ compiler (gcc) thinks function is `virtual' field?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a the following method definition in my class:

```
virtual Calc* Compile(
  Evaluator* evaluator, ResolvedFunCall* fun_call, string* error);
```

For some reason, GCC complains that:

`error: 'Compile' declared as a 'virtual' field`

Any ideas why it would believe Compile to be a field, instead of a method?

Comment: Can you show us the code above and below this?  Were there any other errors.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I get that error when the first parameter doesn't make sense to it. Check that `Evaluator` is known as type:

```
struct A {
    virtual void* b(nonsense*, string*);
};

=> error: 'b' declared as a 'virtual' field

struct A {
    virtual void* b(string*, nonsense*);
};

=> error: 'nonsense' has not been declared
```

To find out whether something is a object or function declaration, the compiler sometimes has to scan the whole declaration. Any construct within the declaration that could possibly form a declaration is taken to be a declaration. If not, then any such construct is taken to be an expression. GCC apparently thinks because `nonsense` is no valid type, it can't be a valid parameter declaration, and thus falls back treating the whole declaration as a field (note that it says in addition *`error: expected ';' before '(' token`* ) . Same thing in local scope

```
int main() {
    int a;

    // "nonsense * a" not treated as declaration
    void f(nonsense*a);
}

=> error: variable or field 'f' declared void

int main() {
    // "nonsense * a" treated as parameter declaration
    typedef int nonsense;
    void f(nonsense*a);
}

=> (compiles successfully)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I declared a virtual function with `{}` instead of `()`.

A sample to demonstrate the error:

test.h

```
class Test{
public:
Test(){}
~Test(){}
//next line is defective, use () instead of {}
virtual int myfunct{int i};//notice brackets here which causes the error
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"//i omitted include guards for simplicity
int Test::myfunct(int x){
    x=5;
    return x;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int main(){
    Test test;
    return 0;
    }
```